# Why is this user's reputation shown as 1 in all sites on the mobile app?

Tags: discussion, mobile-app

In searching in SE app, I found a profile like this:

[image]

It is clear that the profile has a lot of reputation. But why is his rep shown as 1 in all sites?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The apps don’t show [suspensions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/), so you need to view the profile in a browser:

> [image]

As you can see, all the profiles of this user are suspended for a very long time, generally a sign of serious rule breaking.

Comment: What is a profile suspension? Why does it happen?

Comment: @AsifIqubal https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125268/278659

Comment: His suspension ended almost 27 years ago.  Why is it still shown?

Comment: @Mark When I said "a very long time", I actually meant ["until 2292"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319634/why-not-perma-ban-instead-of-suspend-an-account-for-75-years#comment1047333_319634). Sorry for the confusion.