# Stack Exchange’s date system won’t work in 89 years

Tags: support, status-completed, fun, dates

I was looking at an old post, and noticed how we display dates from a certain amount of time ago:

[image: Answered May 10 '11 at 10:56]

This is very non-futureproof design. How will people living in the melted remains of society in 89 years know the difference in age between a question from 2009 and a question from 2109?

**This is a glaring issue that will really detract from my experience using this site *in less than* 90 *years.***

Comment: There is no reason to ask this question now as opposed to in 2099.

Comment: That's quite a bit of user retention if 102 year olds are still using the site

Comment: I also suspect that the *internal* date system's probably something else.

Comment: I **demand** to fix this issue or present a usable workaround no later than in 85 years.

Comment: We always default to showing the least necessary information. For example, we often don't say a year at all if it's the current year. So, it follows that once the four-digit year doesn't match the current century, we'll start showing "'011". :D

Comment: As pointed out in comment to another question, this already appears in some situations: [Why not perma-ban instead of suspend an account for 75+ years?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319634) The user in question is suspended until 2292, shown as '92.

Comment: I've been talking about this problem as far back as '94,

Comment: The real question is, are we going to be affected by the 2038 problem? ;p

Comment: People won't actually consider this an issue until it's closer than _literally almost 90 years from now_. -1

Comment: The full information is in there (is in the HTML content). Try to hover over that very the date (nice red hand circle) and you will see a full date and at 1 second resolution, e.g. 2011-05-10 10:56:19Z. It is a string and is not subject to reinterpretation 7900 years from now (provided it is remembered what the [Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) is or was). The accumulative error of that calendar by then will be a little over 2 days compared to the tropical year. Something was apparently learned from [Y2K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem).

Comment: Thank for reporting! This will be fixed in 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: And yet, no one mistakes May 10 '11 with May 10 1911. How come? Because technology has advanced so much in the last 30 years, we *know* that '11 must refer to this century. What makes you think that people in the future will confuse May 10 2111 with May 10 2011? That far ahead in the future, looking at SE websites will be like looking at daguerreotype photos

Comment: Is this fun? I think this is fun. This is fun, isn't it? This is fun. We hate fun.

Comment: To be fixed in 6-8 decades.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Have a look at [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhQl3.png). Probably an old suspension, right? I'll tell you one thing, though: that screenshot was taken *this* year, in 2019. Confused, eh?

Comment: This is now resolved: [Years in dates will now display with all four digits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376047/years-in-dates-will-now-display-with-all-four-digits)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Now they will](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376047/51)

> Date in far future
> Worried about two digits?
> Fret no more, all good

Comment: Four digits for dates... Makes a lot of sense to me. Thanks, Mr Ellis.

Answer (score 10):

Despite some users making comments that "this question won't be relevant until decades from now", there is one case where this actually ends up being a problem *today*.

The same date format you mention, that is used for posts, is used in a lot of different places in the system (e.g. comments, revisions, etc.). One of those places is the expiration date and time for suspensions.

There have been a few cases lately where *really long* network-wide suspensions have been applied, specifically suspensions with an ending time *after* 2100. One case where this ended up becoming *really* confusing is [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327015/users-suspension-period-has-expired-but-theyre-still-suspended?noredirect=1), where a user was suspended until 2118, but the timestamp simply showed "`'18`", which made users think that it was a bug, that a suspension was supposed to expire but for some reason didn't.

Without a way to represent dates after 2100 in the current global timestamp format, it will create confusing cases like this.

<sub>Yes, I'm also aware of [this other case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319634/why-not-perma-ban-instead-of-suspend-an-account-for-75-years) of a user suspended until 2292 but the timestamp only showing `'92`, but that's much less confusing than the other one.</sub>