# Why can't they just delete the account instead of suspending a user network-wide for more than a century?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, account-suspension, ban, network-wide-suspension

- On [this question,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319634/why-not-perma-ban-instead-of-suspend-an-account-for-75-years) a user is mentioned who is "suspended" till **2292**, which means the suspension period expires on the **23rd century** (2201-2300).
- [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327015/users-suspension-period-has-expired-but-theyre-still-suspended?noredirect=1&lq=1) mentions another user who is suspended until **2118**, which is the **22nd century** (2101-2200).

---

Why can't they just delete the account instead of doing like this?

Comment: You even find people banned "into the past" See https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/1370/ron-maimon

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why not perma-ban instead of suspend an account for 275 years?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319634/why-not-perma-ban-instead-of-suspend-an-account-for-275-years), see Brad Larson's answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Think about it that way: all the information that sits in your account is still "yours".

Banning you means that you can't do anything that has effects on other users.

But you can come in and **check** on your content. Whereas deleting your account deprives you from doing so.

In other words: a *ban* is visible to others, and it prevents you from any kind of *interaction* with other users. That prevents the banned user from causing further harm.

But as said: their "content" and the information around that, is still "theirs". There is no point in taking that away from them.

---

<sup>And from a philosophical point of view: I think there are examples of users that received serious bans, but who learned their lesson and asked for the ban being lifted. To then become very helpful members of the community. With "capital punishment" (account deletion), that would not have been possible. But this is kinda hearsay from my memory.</sup>

Comment: of course, nobody could ever create a sock puppet account.....

Comment: It's also bad form.  It just looks petty and vindictive rules lawyering

Comment: *"There is no point in taking that away from them"* Also, I've heard that content laws affect this decision. Deleting an account might violate the user's right to their own intellectual property, since the post is no longer attributed to them. That's one argument I've heard as to why **SE pretty much only deletes accounts upon the user's request nowadays** (just to be on the safe side). IANAL, though if this were confirmed by someone who knows what they're doing, I'd be glad to see this edited into this answer.

Comment: @RichardsaysReinstateMonica A sock puppet is the same person. But it is a different avatar, that starts with reputation 1 and privileges 0. Not very attractive for users that already established a decent number of posts.

Comment: @GhostCatsaysReinstateMonica maybe not, but the point is, it won't stop them.